# Solve for $x$: $10^x=x+100$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, transcendental-equations

I don't know how to solve it: $$10^x=x+100$$
The original question was how many answers are there, so I drew the functions, then I see there are 2 answers (cuts?).
I really want to know how to solve and know the actual answers, but I don't really know how to solve it.
In general how do I solve equations which got $x$, $a^x$, $c$, and more...

*Which tags should I put? 
*How do I write in the math font? I always see the math font, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: you can have a look on mathjax. see for example here :)
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I'm afraid that you'll never be able to get a closed form for the solutions. Unless you like W-Lambert function.

Comment: for the actual answers, i'm not sure that there exists a proper way to solve it, 2 solutions seems to be really ugly, even wolfram alpha can not give an exact formula
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%5Ex%3Dx%2B100
perhaps the best way is to argue using the monotonicity of the derivative of the function $f (x) = 10^x -x - 100$ then conclude that there are two solution in $(-101,-99)$ and $(2,3)$ as $f(-101) \cdot f(-99) < 0$ and $f(2) \cdot f(3) < 0$

Comment: Wolfram formula gave something with W, I guess it is related to what Zubzub said...
But how then wolfram got to the correct answers? Can someone try to explain what the W Lambert function is in easy explain? *nvm

Comment: @YuvalTuby You basically want to reach $C=f(x)e^{f(x)}$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Can you explain more about it? I don't really understand.
In the final x you gave, what is the W? A number?

Comment: @YuvalTuby $W$ is the Lambert W function. We have$$f(x)=W(c)\implies C=f(x)e^{f(x)}$$

Comment: I understand, thanks. But in the final answer, what is W?

Comment: No, it's the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) but you should probably start with some simpler problems.

Comment: @Nick Can you send me to place I read more easily (maybe not wikipedia?), and place with problems I can start with?

Comment: Generally speaking, the only way to solve transcendental equations is numerically. You can define transcendental functions (like exponentials, logarithms, trigonometric functions etc) to solve some of the simpler ones explicitly, but even then you have to go to tables (or your calculator) for explicit values. This one requires a different function, unfamiliar to most people, but you can find its values in a table and use it to calculate x as in the answer below. Most pre-calc textbooks have sections on (the simpler) transcendental functions and problems to practice with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an iterative method like

$$x=\log_{10}(x+100).$$

Starting from any initial guess $x>-100+1.0000000001\times10^{-100}$ and you'll get the answer in a few iterations: $x=2.008636944$. Another answer is very close to $x=-100$, which can be reached by the iteration

$$x=-100+10^x$$

starting from $x=-100$ as the initial guess. Then the solution is $x\approx-100+10^{-100}$.

Comment: Can you explain more how you got to the answer? Why $x=log(x+100)$? Did you decide it will be this?

Comment: Because the equation was $10^x=x+100$. Just take the base-10 log on both sides.

Comment: Oh yeh I get it. Ok so $x>-100$, but there should be 2 answers, wolfram says the second answer is $-100$, but if $x>-100$, how $x=-100$?
How did you get to 2.008...?

Comment: The iterative method means to start from an initial guess. For example $x=0$. Plug it into the right-hand side to obtain $x=2$. Then plug it in again to obtain $x=2.0086$, etc, until you get an answer with the required accuracy.

Comment: Wow this is really cool, why is this working and going in the end to the final answer? I tried to start for example with 50, and I did again and again, until I came to 2.0086... What about the second answer? $x=-100$.
What will happen if I have 3 answers, 4,5,.. How then I will find the solutions?
Sorry for annoying, but what will you when: $10^x=100x^3+50x^2$ , there are 3 solutions.

Comment: $x=-100$ is not an answer. $x+100=10^x$ has to be positive. There is no second answer. In general iterative methods only find one solution depending on the initial guess.

Comment: But $10^x$ and $x+100$ have 2 cut points, Then why do you say there is no second answer?

Comment: Oh, yes. The second solution is very close to $x=-100$. It is approximately $-100+10^{-100}$. It is unstable in the logarithmic iteration scheme, but can be reached using $x=10^x-100$ from the initial guess $x=-100$, even though any floating point system cannot calculate $-100+10^{-100}$.

Comment: Oh nice. Probably what I'm going to say it stupid but anyway, At first you "made alone"(how do you say it?) the $x$ from the $10^x$ and used the "initial guess" for first solution. Then you "made alone" the $x$ that already alone from $x+100$ and used the "initial guess" for second solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe that WA didn't succeed.

$$10^x=x+100$$

$$10^{-100}e^{\log10(x+100)}=x+100$$

$$-10^{-100}\log10=-\log10(x+100)e^{-\log10(x+100)}$$

$$W(-10^{-100}\log10)=-\log10(x+100).$$

Comment: Oh whoops, it seems I missed a negative in my comment.

Comment: By WA you mean W-Lambert funtion?
What is the W,  I don't get it?
What do I put as W to get the answers?

Comment: @YuvalTuby No, [WA = WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com)

Comment: @YvesDaoust what did you input into WA?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: nothing. The OP did.

Comment: @YuvalTuby You *put* nothing for $W$, it is a function (Lambert W function) which is used to rearrange such kind of equations. There is no other elementary way.

Comment: @M.Winter But but but, how do you get then to the actual answers? W has to be something you put there a number no?

Comment: @YuvalTuby Please look it up. It is a function like $\sin$ or $\log$ which cannot be expressed in terms of other functions *except* that it is the inverse of $x\exp(x)$. You can compute it with a sufficiently good calculator like WolframAlpha, or by taylor expansion.

Comment: Oh, so is there calculators, which calculate the answer that inculdes $W$ in it, and give the asnwer?

Comment: @YuvalTuby Yes. E.g. WolframAlpha if you want to call it a calculator.